# Programmatically duplicate item

Tags: magento

Using Magento, I'm attempting to duplicate items in a quote.

I have seen that you can duplicate a product simply by using: `$newProduct = $product->duplicate();`, however I’m not having any such luck with quote items.

Here is what I’ve tried, (for example) attempting to duplicate the item 3 times in the cart:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
    $quote->addItem($item->duplicate());
}
```

but all I get is this lousy error message:

`Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::duplicate`

Any ideas for other things to try?

Answer (score 1):

May try this

```
$productId = 201;
$pData = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId)->getData();
$pData['entity_id'] = null;

Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setData($pData)->save();
```